# Error in access to Entity Framework data from WCF service in web and win form application?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

I am in the middle of big web application, I use Entity Framework as my data service, now we need some windows application to work with our data, so I want to give them a service with WCF

But when my client wants to get service some error is happened from my public property which I use for caching Entity Model

```
    public partial class DepositEntities : ObjectContext
    {
        public static DepositEntities Current
        {
            get
            {
                DepositEntities oc = 
                    HttpContext.Current.Items["ObjectContext"] as DepositEntities;

                if (oc == null)
                {
                    oc = new DepositEntities();
                    HttpContext.Current.Items["ObjectContext"] = oc;
                }

                return oc;
            }
        }
    }
```

I know the problem is from this line, after I debug my code

```
DepositEntities oc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["ObjectContext"] as DepositEntities;
```

When I change my `Current` property body to some thing like this

```
public static DepositEntities Current
{
   get
   {
      DepositEntities oc = new DepositEntities();
      return oc;
   }
}
```

everything is OK when I get data from services I have no problem

But everywhere I have join in my codes I have problem because It thinks there are different data source because of `new DepositEntities();`

Comment: Does it raise an exception or just not give back any data?

Comment: Dear @LosFrijoles Exception is just **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.** for this line {DepositEntities oc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Items["ObjectContext"] as DepositEntities;}  but this line works correctly in my whole project when I want to use WCF I get this error

Comment: The `HttpContext` only exists in the context of an ASP.NET web application. A Windows Forms application doesn't have an `HttpContext` so you cannot use it to cache data..... you need to check out some other means of caching that's not depedent on `HttpContext`.

Comment: @marc_s give me some alternative !?

Comment: You could check out the new .NET 4 [`System.Runtime.Caching`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd985642.aspx) namespace for general purpose caching that is available to all project types and doesn't depend on a `HttpContext` or anything

Comment: @marc_s That was great idea but didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're most likely experiencing problems because WCF doesn't have HttpContext.Current. Read more about contexts in WCF - this question may be a good start: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/27896125-b61e-42bd-a1b0-e6da5c23e6fc.

I also think it would be better for you to manage lifetime of an ObjectContext with a DI Container (ie. [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html)). Thanks to this, it won't be necessary to expose static property Current which is a problem for WCF service, unit tests, etc.

Comment: your answer seems correct but I couldn't find my solution it's a little complicated for me! can you tell me which session should I use to solve the problem !?

Comment: I change my way! I use Web Service in my client instead of using WCF

Answer (score 1):

Check out "Hosting WCF Services in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode" in [wcf service and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx). It explains how to get a valid HttpContext in a wcf service.